# How to store a const char* in std :: string?

Tags: c++, string, pointers, stl

```
    char       *buffer1 = "abc";

    const char *buffer2 = (const char*) buffer;

    std :: string str (buffer2);
```

This works, but I want to declare the *std::string* object i.e. *str*, **once** and use it many times to store different *const char**.

What's the way out?

Comment: please clarify what you want to be able to do, possibly with an example of code that you would want to work. (the code you posted doesn't make much sens)

Comment: @Mat Ah, well, soon after posting this question, I found the easy solution too :doh: `std :: string str (buffer2);` One simple way to store that const char* is to use the `append` function of the stl class! Like `std :: string str; str.append (buffer2);`
`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can just re-assign:

```
const char *buf1 = "abc";
const char *buf2 = "def";

std::string str(buf1);

str = buf2; // Calls str.operator=(const char *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Ah well, as I commented above, found the answer soon after posting the question :doh:

```
    const char* g;
    g = (const char*)buffer;

    std :: string str;
    str.append (g);
```

So, I can call append() function as many times (after using the clear()) as I want on the same object with "const char *".

Though the "push_back" function won't work in place of "append".

Comment: `assign` would be more expressive (and shorter and clearer) then `clear` followed by `append`, but a simple assignment using `=` will work just as well.

Answer (score 1):

`str` is actually copying the characters from `buffer2`, so it is not connected in any way.

If you want it to have another value, you just assign a new one

```
str = "Hello";
```

Answer (score -1):

Make a Class say MyString which compose String buffer.
Have a constant of that class.
and then u can reassign the value of the composed string buffer, while using the same constant.